# All masters are unresponsive! Giving up. in Spark

Tags: docker, apache-spark, airflow

I made Airflow with Spark using Docker.

hen I command directly using spark image

```
docker exec -it 156a5194034b(=spark-master container name) \
    spark-submit --master spark://405456c06b6c:7077 \
    /usr/local/spark/app/script.py
```

it works well.

An error occurs when using the SparkSubmitOperator in an Airflow DAG.
Below is error log.

```
24/01/01 01:02:18 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connecting to master spark://405456c06b6c:7077...
24/01/01 01:02:18 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to 405456c06b6c/172.18.0.3:7077 after 44 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
24/01/01 01:02:38 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connecting to master spark://405456c06b6c:7077...
24/01/01 01:02:58 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connecting to master spark://405456c06b6c:7077...
24/01/01 01:03:18 ERROR StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Application has been killed. Reason: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.
```

After Airflow successfully connects with Spark, it attempts to connect two more times, and the following error occurs. SparkSession automatically stops.

Any ideas?